# Should I always use a SafeArea at the top level of my flutter screens?

Tags: flutter

I am curious if I should always use a SafeArea widget at the top level of my screen. I mean....when would I want my content blocked by things like a notch? For me it seems like the answer is never.

So should I not just use SafeArea on every page? If so, should it be above or below the Scaffold widget?

Comment: you can have a reusable `Scaffold` widget with the `SafeArea` as its `body` and use this reusable widget whenever you build a new Page/Screen

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to use `SafeArea` on every screen. It actually depends if an `AppBar` is used or not, because the `AppBar` automatically calculates the values and adds the required padding.

If you use it above a `Scaffold` the area where the padding is applied would be black. On the other hand, if you use it below the `Scaffold` the color of the area would depend on the app theme, probably the `Scaffold` background color.

Answer (score 1):

If you won't add an app bar or add it. if you want to adjust the screen to be responsive using MediaQuery and you don't need any scroll inside the screen use it.

Use it as the first widget in the body of the scaffold.